# Update JTextArea text in JFrame from Custom JDialog output data or results

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtextarea, jdialog

I have a `JTextArea` inside a main layout that I want to update using a custom `JDialog`. Difficult to explain in words like this...so please just follow code and explanation process as outlined below:

1. I have a JPanel that contains the JTextArea (i.e. original JTextArea - 'cancellationPolicTA') that needs to be updated:

   ```
   public class Panel_Other_Information extends JPanel {

   private JTextArea cancellationPolicyTA, otherInformationTA;
   public final String cancellationPolicyBorderTXT = " Cancellation Policy ";
   public final String additionalInformationBorderTXT = " Other Information ";

   public Panel_Other_Information () {

       // Create and set up the window.
       JPanel thisPanel = new JPanel ();

       // [1] Define the Dimensions of the Panel.
       Dimension panelSize = getPreferredSize();
       panelSize.width = 520;
       panelSize.height = 100;
       setPreferredSize(panelSize);
       setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(" 15. Additional Information "));

       // [2] Use the 'SpringLayout' to set or define the layout of components within this panel.
       SpringLayout layout = new SpringLayout();
       setLayout(layout);
       setBackground(McGyver.APP_THEME_COLOR);

       // [3] Define required Label components/controls.
       JLabel cancellationPolicyLabel = new JLabel ("Cancellation Policy:");
       JLabel otherInformationLabel = new JLabel ("Other Information:");
       String canPolTxt = "No Cancellation Policy";
       String othInfTxt = "No Additional Information";

       // [4] Define required input (TextField) controls/components.
       final int widthCB = 230;
       final int heightCB = 48;
       cancellationPolicyTA = new JTextArea(canPolTxt);
       cancellationPolicyTA.setEditable(false);
       cancellationPolicyTA.setWrapStyleWord(true);
       cancellationPolicyTA.addMouseListener(new CancelPolicyMouseListener());
       cancellationPolicyTA.addFocusListener(new CancelPolicyFocusListener());

       otherInformationTA = new JTextArea(othInfTxt);
       otherInformationTA.setEditable(false);
       otherInformationTA.setWrapStyleWord(true);
       otherInformationTA.addMouseListener(new OtherInformationMouseListener());

       JScrollPane canPolTAScrollPane = new JScrollPane(cancellationPolicyTA);
       canPolTAScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(widthCB, heightCB));
       JScrollPane otherInfoTAScrollPane = new JScrollPane(otherInformationTA);
       otherInfoTAScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(widthCB, heightCB));

       // [5] Define button controls - if needed.
       /* JButton saveDataBTN = new JButton("Save"); */

       ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
       //      Define the layout of components - component-by-component      //
       ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

       /* -- Component 1 - Additional Information - Cancellation Policy Label */
       layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, cancellationPolicyLabel, 5, SpringLayout.NORTH, thisPanel);
       layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, cancellationPolicyLabel, 0, SpringLayout.EAST, thisPanel);

       /* -- Component 2 - Additional Information - Cancellation Policy Text Area */
       layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, canPolTAScrollPane, 5, SpringLayout.SOUTH, cancellationPolicyLabel);
       layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, canPolTAScrollPane, 0, SpringLayout.WEST, cancellationPolicyLabel);

       /* -- Component 1 - Additional Information - Cancellation Policy Label */
       layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, otherInformationLabel, 5, SpringLayout.NORTH, thisPanel);
       layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, otherInformationLabel, 30, SpringLayout.EAST, canPolTAScrollPane);

       /* -- Component 2 - Additional Information - Cancellation Policy Text Area */
       layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, otherInfoTAScrollPane, 5, SpringLayout.SOUTH, otherInformationLabel);
       layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, otherInfoTAScrollPane, 0, SpringLayout.WEST, otherInformationLabel);

       // [4] Add Swing components to content pane.
       add(cancellationPolicyLabel);
       add(canPolTAScrollPane);
       add(otherInformationLabel);
       add(otherInfoTAScrollPane);
   }

   private class CancelPolicyMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {

       public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){

           if(e.getClickCount() == 1){

               String cancelPolicyText = cancellationPolicyTA.getText();

               if (cancelPolicyText.length() > 0) {

                   String dialogTitle = "15. Additional Information";
                   String borderTitle = cancellationPolicyBorderTXT;

                   McGyver.popCustomDialogTextAreaObject(dialogTitle, borderTitle, cancelPolicyText);
               }
           }
       }
   } }
   ```

Please take NOTE of the last bit of code above >> this is where the custom JDialog gets fired or called from.

2. I have the main class that runs the whole application:

   ```
   public class Stan_App extends JFrame {

   // [1] Instantiate all SWING components needed for this application.
   public static Stan_App stanFrame;
   private McGyver mcGyver = new McGyver();
   public Panel_Other_Information additionalInformation = new Panel_Other_Information();

   public Stan_App (String title) {
       super(title);

       // [1] Set LayoutManager
       SpringLayout layout = new SpringLayout();
       setLayout(layout);
       setBackground(Color.CYAN);

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
       //   [2]  Define the layout of components - component-by-component    //
       ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

       //-- Component 1 - JPanel - Additional Information --//
       layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, additionalInformation, 17, SpringLayout.SOUTH, neighbourhoodRating);
       layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, additionalInformation, 20, SpringLayout.EAST, inRoomFacilities);


       // [3] Add Swing components to content pane.
       Container conTain = getContentPane();
       conTain.add(additionalInformation);
   }

   public static void main (String[] args) {

       SwingUtilities.invokeLater (new Runnable() {

           @Override
           public void run() {

               createStanAppGUI();
           }
       });
   }

   private static void createStanAppGUI () {

       // Override the default Font for the application.
       McGyver.setUIFont(McGyver.APP_GLOBAL_FONT);

       // This code chuck lays out the visual components (GUI) of the app.
       stanFrame = new Stan_App (" S.T.A. Namibia  -  Database Manager " + "   |   THEME: " + McGyver.currentlySelectedAppThemeColor + "   |");
       // UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("defaultFont", new Font("Noto Sans", Font.BOLD, 42));
       stanFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
       stanFrame.setSize(1925, 1050);
       stanFrame.setResizable(false);
       stanFrame.setVisible(true);

       themeColorCB.setSelectedItem(McGyver.currentlySelectedAppThemeColor);
   }
   public void setCancellationTextFromCustomPopupDialog (String suppliedText) {
       additionalInformation.setCancellation_Policy_TextArea_Value(suppliedText);
   } }
   ```
3. I have a special helper class - where I keep all my useful code for implementation  throughout the application:

   ```
   public class McGyver {

   public static JDialog custPopupDialog;

   public static void popCustomDialogTextAreaObject (String dialogTitle, String borderTitle, String inputString) {

       Panel_Custom_Dialog custDial = new Panel_Custom_Dialog(Stan_App.stanFrame, borderTitle, inputString);

       final int widthCB = 500;
       final int heightCB = 400;

       custPopupDialog = new JDialog();
       custPopupDialog.setTitle(dialogTitle);
       custPopupDialog.add(custDial);
       custPopupDialog.setSize(new Dimension(widthCB, heightCB)); /* Size(550, 450); */
       custPopupDialog.setModal(true);
       custPopupDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
       custPopupDialog.setVisible(true);
   } }
   ```

Please NOTE: I have obviously cleaned up the code a lot to show only the important parts.

The Custom Dialog I need pulls all the current text from the JTextArea when the JTextArea is clicked on and then allows the user to continue editing the text inside another JTextArea in the custom JDialog (i.e. custPopupDialog). When the user clicks on the 'OKAY' button inside the custom JDialog the text from the custom dialog should be fed back to the original (i.e. cancellationPolicTA) JTextArea of the main class.

Everything works fine (i.e. data gets pulled into the custom JDialog and JDialog is displayed properly), but the text data is NOT handed back to the original JTextArea when the user clicks on the 'OKAY' button inside the custom JDialog. Please help. Thanks in advance.

4. I forgot to paste in the Custom JDialog code - (see below):

> public class Panel_Custom_Dialog extends JPanel {

```
Stan_App stanAPP;
String borderHeaderString, editedCancellationPolicyTXT;
private JTextArea custDialogTA;
private Panel_Other_Information otherInfoPanel = new Panel_Other_Information();

public Panel_Custom_Dialog (Stan_App stanApp, String borderTitle, String inputMessageString) {

    stanAPP = stanApp;

    // Create and set up the window.
    JPanel thisPanel = new JPanel();
    borderHeaderString = null;

    if (borderTitle == null) {

        borderHeaderString = " Section Header Here! ";

    } else {

        borderHeaderString = borderTitle;
    }

    // [1] Define the Dimensions of the Panel.
    Dimension panelSize = getPreferredSize();
    panelSize.width = 500;
    panelSize.height = 400;
    setPreferredSize(panelSize);
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(borderHeaderString));

    // [2] Use the 'SpringLayout' to set or define the layout of components within this panel.
    SpringLayout layout = new SpringLayout();
    setLayout(layout);
    setBackground(McGyver.APP_THEME_COLOR);

    // [3] Define the
    final int widthCB = 450;
    final int heightCB = 300;

    // [4] Define the required components for this Panel.
    custDialogTA = new JTextArea(inputMessageString);
    custDialogTA.setBounds(5, 5, 0, 0);
    custDialogTA.setLineWrap(true);
    custDialogTA.setWrapStyleWord(true);

    JScrollPane custDialogTextAreaScrollPane = new JScrollPane(custDialogTA);
    custDialogTextAreaScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(widthCB, heightCB));

    // [3] Define the Button size fields.
    final int widthBTN = 100;
    final int heightBTN = 25;

    JButton affirmativeBTN = new JButton(" OKAY "); affirmativeBTN.addActionListener(new CustomDialogAffirmationActionListener());
    JButton cancellationBTN = new JButton(" CANCEL "); cancellationBTN.addActionListener(new CustomDialogCancellationActionListener());
    affirmativeBTN.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(widthBTN, heightBTN));
    cancellationBTN.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(widthBTN, heightBTN));

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //      Define the layout of components - component-by-component      //
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    /* -- Component 1 - Additional Information - Custom Dialog TextArea */
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, custDialogTextAreaScrollPane, 5, SpringLayout.NORTH, thisPanel);
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, custDialogTextAreaScrollPane, 0, SpringLayout.EAST, thisPanel);

    /* -- Component 2 - Additional Information - Custom Dialog Affirmation  Button */
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, affirmativeBTN, 10, SpringLayout.SOUTH, custDialogTextAreaScrollPane);
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, affirmativeBTN, 0, SpringLayout.EAST, thisPanel);

    /* -- Component 3 - Additional Information - Custom Dialog Cancellation Button */
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, cancellationBTN, 0, SpringLayout.NORTH, affirmativeBTN);
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, cancellationBTN, 25, SpringLayout.EAST, affirmativeBTN);

    // [5] Add the components defined above to the panel.
    add(custDialogTextAreaScrollPane);
    add(affirmativeBTN);
    add(cancellationBTN);
}


public String getCust_Dialog_TextArea_Value () {

    return custDialogTA.getText();
}

public void setCust_Dialog_TextArea_Value (String inputString) {

    custDialogTA.setText(inputString);
}

private class CustomDialogAffirmationActionListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (borderHeaderString.equals(otherInfoPanel.cancellationPolicyBorderTXT)) {

            editedCancellationPolicyTXT = custDialogTA.getText();

            stanAPP.setCancellationTextFromCustomPopupDialog(editedCancellationPolicyTXT);

            McGyver.custPopupDialog.dispose();

        } else if (borderHeaderString.equals(otherInfoPanel.additionalInformationBorderTXT)) {

            editedCancellationPolicyTXT = custDialogTA.getText();

            stanAPP.setOtherInformationTextFromCustomPopupDialog(editedCancellationPolicyTXT);

            McGyver.custPopupDialog.dispose();
        }
    }
}

private class CustomDialogCancellationActionListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        McGyver.custPopupDialog.dispose();
    }
} }
```

Comment: I do not see a method in your McGyver class that returns the updated text, to update the cancellationPolicyTA. the custPopupDialog is Modal, so you it should block until the user hits ok and cancel, then you can return the updated text

Comment: Faljbour, can you please explain that with a code example because I am finding it hard to get what you are saying.

Comment: I added the code example, let me know if still not clear

Comment: you do not need an additional method to return the updated text you can either keep getCust_Dialog_TextArea_Value or getInputString

Comment: Thanks, Faljbour...I realized that - will clean it up later - was just comparing your code to mine first. But that still doesn't solve the problem. Is there perhaps something else I am not doing right that is blocking or negating the updating of the text in the original JTextArea?

Comment: I see that you have   stanAPP = new Stan_App(""); which has your main method, inside of the Panel_Custom_Dialog class, you must have two stanAPP instantiated or  I must be missing something. you should look at the flow of your classes.

Comment: Oh my goodness. Thanks, Faljbour. that was the problem. It's working now. I passed the Stan_App instance from the main class (i.e. Stan_App class) to the constructor of the 'Panel_Custom_Dialog' class...and then referenced that in the helper class (i.e. McGyver) where the popCustDialog method was being run from. That solved the problem. So if you add that as the answer, I can give you a few vote up. Thanks again.

Comment: Faljbour - I have updated the code to reflect the fixes made to get the code working as required. Thanks

Comment: I just added the to the answer to remove the stanApp instantiation from the panel_custom_dialog class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See some of the code updated with comments,

First remove the stanAPP = new Stan_App(""); from the Panel_Custom_Dialog class and pass a reference to it, since it should have been instantiated else where,

```
McGyver.popCustomDialogTextAreaObject(dialogTitle, borderTitle, cancelPolicyText);

//* the popCustomDialog is Modal, this code above should block until the user hits ok or cancel, 
String updatedText = McGyver.getInputString();
cancellationPolicyTA.setText(updatedText);
```

In the Mcgyver class and the popCustomDialogTExtAreaObject you need methods that will return the updated text. see the added method below with comments,

```
public class McGyver {

public static JDialog custPopupDialog;
public static Panel_Custom_Dialog custDial

public static void popCustomDialogTextAreaObject (String dialogTitle, String borderTitle, String inputString) {

    custDial = new Panel_Custom_Dialog(borderTitle, inputString);

    final int widthCB = 500;
    final int heightCB = 400;

    custPopupDialog = new JDialog();
    custPopupDialog.setTitle(dialogTitle);
    custPopupDialog.add(custDial);
    custPopupDialog.setSize(new Dimension(widthCB, heightCB)); /* Size(550, 450); */
    custPopupDialog.setModal(true);
    custPopupDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    custPopupDialog.setVisible(true);
  } 
  //* add a method that will return the updated string.  
  //* for this to work, Panel_Custom_Dialog should have a method that will return the updated text
  public static string getInputString()
  {
    return custDial.getInputString();  
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion Faljbour, but it's still not working. Upon the click on the affirmation button in the 'Panel_Custom_Dialog' there is a final dispose method. Doesn't this kill off all the data passed from the 'Panel_Custom_Dialog'? If so then calling 'custDial.getInputString()' will not yield any data, will it? I'm not so clear on this...please advise. Thanks

Comment: this is just an idea oh how you should design the code, you need a method to return the modified updated text from the Panel_Custom_Dialog which should be passed back to the cancellationPolicyTA.  Did you add that method, you may want to show the code for the Panel_Custom_Dialog.  To answer you question, yes it will yield data.

Comment: Faljbour, I added the 'Panel_Custom_Dialog' code now.

Comment: based on the additional code you added, it should work fine even after the dialog is returned and disposed.